# How To Configure openam SAML2 service provider to use NameID Format unspecified

Tags: single-sign-on, saml, openam

currently, we use openAM version 13.0.0 as a service provider for SAML2 SSO.

How To Configure openAM SAML2 service provider to use NameID Format unspecified?

Edit : 
I faced the following issue :

ERROR: spAssertionConsumer.jsp: SSO failed. com.sun.identity.saml2.common.SAML2Exception: No local user being mapped. at com.sun.identity.saml2.profile.SPACSUtils.processResponse(SPACSUtils.java:1225)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given you use `spSSOInit.jsp` to trigger SP-initiated SSO flow, you can specify the NameID format to be sent (`NameIDPolicy` element in SAML AuthNRequest) by using request parameter `NameIDFormat`. If it's supported by the SP and IdP, it will be used. If you do not specify this request parameter, OpenAM tries to find the first NameID format that is supported by both entities. If the IDP does not specify anything, the first NameID format of the hosted SP is used.

Comment: i faced the following issue :
ERROR: spAssertionConsumer.jsp: SSO failed.
com.sun.identity.saml2.common.SAML2Exception: No local user being mapped.
 at com.sun.identity.saml2.profile.SPACSUtils.processResponse(SPACSUtils.java:1225)
 at org.apache.jsp.saml2.jsp.spAssertionConsumer_jsp._jspService(spAssertionConsumer_jsp.java:284)
 at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
 at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:439)

Comment: waiting for your support @Bernhard Thalmayr

Comment: When the SAML response is consumed and you have configured 'Profile required' set in authentication service, then OpenAM tries to find a profile in the configured user data stores. The value being used for the search in the user data store depends on your configuration.

Comment: thanks for your support.

how can we solve this issue?